# Python - Dataframe names for a function expression

Tags: python

New to Python.

I have a function which requires a number of pandas dataframes. eg:

```
def funct(a,b,c,d)
```

I have a list which contains the dataframe names. eg:

```
datanames = ['a','b','c','d']
```

When I unpack the list to call the function it treats them a strings, not dataframes. eg:

```
funct(*datanames)
```

Is there anyway of `unpacking a list of dataframe` names so that they are recognised as `dataframes`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rather than passing name of data frames separately pass whole list to function and then unpack it like this  `def someFunc(myList = [], *args)
    for x in myList:
        print x `

Comment: You unpack a list of names (strings) and it treats them as strings. If you want the dataframes shouldn't you unpack a list of dataframes?